# Creating an SVN patch including new directories

Tags: svn, new-operator, patch, directory

First of all excuse the long text, but I am trying to be as detailed as I can.

I am developing for an open-source project (DSpace). I don't have commit privileges to their SVN repo, so I checked out the source and have been using git to manage my versioning.

During my development, i've added several directories and binary files to my project.

The time has come to make an SVN patch file so I can give something back to the community! Netbeans does this for me through the Team-> Create patch option. So far so good...

However, when I check out the source again on another machine and use the patch command:

```sh
# get current dir
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )" 

#check out dspace release
svn co http://scm.dspace.org/svn/repo/dspace/tags/dspace-1.7.2/ -q $DIR/dspace-1.7.2/

#apply patch
cd $DIR/dspace-1.7.2
echo "Now running at "&& pwd
patch --dry-run -N -p0 < $DIR/patches/patch.diff
cd $DIR
```

**Running Script**

When i run this script, all goes well until the patch attempts to modify a file inside one of my new directories. It says the following:

```sh
can't find file to patch at input line 9214
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js
|--- dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js         Base (BASE)
|+++ dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js     Locally Modified (Based On LOCAL)
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

**Before it stops, it is able to patch a bunch of files which were already in the original dspace release,** so I think it is not related to the -pXXX parameter of the patch command (nevertheless i have tried up to -p10) ... I think this only happens when I attempt to patch a file inside one of my created directories. **My guess is that the patch command does not create new directories, so it cannot find the correct paths.**

This is driving me nuts, please does anyone have any idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've added the --verbose option to the patch command. Here's the result:

```sh
--------------------------
Patching file dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/autocompleter/styles.css using Plan A...
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1.
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
can't find file to patch at input line 9214
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|Index: dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js
|--- dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js     Base (BASE)
|+++ dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js     Locally Modified (Based On LOCAL)
--------------------------
File to patch:
```

After I quit the patch process, if i make

```sh
cd dspace-1.7.2/dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI
```

I get:

```sh
-bash: cd: dspace-1.7.2/dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-webapp/src/main/webapp/static/js/jQueryUI: No such file or directory
```

This is one of the folders I added during the development, which proves that patch is not creating these new folders.

Comment: Can you show some or all of patch.diff? I don't know how NetBeans generates the patch, but if you add a file or directory in the filesystem and don't tell subversion it should be added, it won't show up in a patch generated by the CLI client.

Comment: I've tried adding all the files in my modified directory through svn add * -- force and then i did the svn diff > patch.diff command. Unfortunately i cannot post the diff file here, since it is an academic work and can only be published after review ... :(

Comment: I think you may need to create the directory and files manually in your checkout - thinking about this further, I don't think subversion supports creating new directories (nor files, I don't think) in patches - svn diff only lists textual differences.

Comment: Yeah, ill try that. Ill create an "overlay" directory structure containing only my new directory and copy it over the root dspace dir from the svn checkout.

Comment: I have decided to Export the DSpace repository into one of my own public repositories just for this. 

Ill create a blank public repository and check in the original distribution of the software. Then Ill check out from my repository, clean the .svn directories in the folder containing my "improved" version and paste it over the folder i check out from my repository.

After that, ill check everything back in and hopefully ill create a patch. I hope someone in the DSpace community will help me figure out how to solve this.

Comment: I still cant believe SVN does not support adding Binary files and dirs (even without diff).

Comment: It does support adding binary files, just not generating patches for them.

Comment: patch-2.5.9 does create the new folders, btw.

Answer (score 0):

In case of generating patches, which have to include adding new files/directories, for pure subversion CLI you have to add `--git` option to `svn diff` command